# Only print defined str_word_count matches?

Tags: php, arrays, count

How can i use `(str_word_count($str, 1))`; as an array and omit words assigned a number by leaving them out... So `Hello [1] => World [2] => This [3] => Is [4] => a [5] => Test ) 6` only outputs the numbers i define, such as [1] and [2] to omit This is a test leaving only leaving Hello World, or [1] and [6] for Hello Test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) or [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$input  = 'Hello World This Is a Test';
$allow  = array('Hello', 'Test');

$data   = explode(' ', $input);
// or your way
$data   = str_word_count($input, 1);


$output = array_intersect($data, $allow);
$count  = count($output);

echo 'Found ' + $count;

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: @HSZ IDK what the allowed words will always be, its for a cipher that has fake words.. so i was hoping to be able to define a number for each word as its count and then print the the words that i need to decode the cipher one step further... So JACK 1 JILL 2 BOB 3 HARRY 4 SECRET 5 SALLY 6 SUE 7 CODE 8 TOM 9... I would print the match or word count id for 5 and 8...

Comment: You mean you just want to get that elements of array by their index? `echo $data[4] + ' ' + $data[7];` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, however when i try to use that instead of echoing SECRET CODE its just returning 0?

Comment: @HSZ Messed around with it a little and using only one index match returns the 4th letter instead of word? Any idea why?

Comment: @Ryan Cooper - because you are using index on a string instead of array.

Comment: @HSZ I have the format set as 2 "2 - returns an associative array, where the key is the numeric position of the word inside the string and the value is the actual word itself." Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 solution

```
$input  = 'Hello World This Is a Test';
$allow  = array('Hello', 'World');

$array = array_filter(
    str_word_count( $input, 1 ),
    function( $v ) use( $allow ) {
        return in_array( $v, $allow ) ? $v : false;
    }
);

print_r( $array );
```