# Print list of defined str_word_count matches within exploded array by index

Tags: php, arrays, count

I previously had some help with [this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871989/536610) from @HSZ but have had trouble getting the solution to work with an existing array. What im trying to do is explode quotes, make all words uppercase plus get each words index value and only echo the ones i define then implode. In simplest terms, always remove the 4th word within quotations or the 3rd and 4th... This could probably done with regex as well.

Example:

`Hello [1] => World [2] => This [3] => Is [4] => a [5] => Test ) 6` only outputs the numbers i define, such as **[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871989/536610) - (Hello)** and **[2] - (World)** leaving out [3], [4], [5] and [6] or **This is a test** leaving only **Hello World**, or [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871989/536610) and [6] for Hello Test...

Such as:

```
echo $data[1] + ' ' + $data[6]; //Would output index 1 and 6 Hello and Test
```

Existing Code

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false) {
$arr = explode('"', $data);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
$arr[$i] = strtoupper($arr[$i]);    
$arr[$i] = str_word_count($arr, 1); // Doesnt work with array of course.
}

$arr = $matches[1] + ' ' + $matches[6];
$data = implode('"', $arr);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem?

Comment: One `str_word_count` expects a string not an array, but my input is already temporarily exploded into an array... I'm basically trying to return index word count values of an array. So that Hello World "This is a test" Hello World with echo `$matches[4]` would become Hello World "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$data` is `'Hello world "this is a test"'`, `$arr = explode('"', $data)` will be the same as:

```
$arr = array (
  [0] => 'Hello World',
  [1] => 'This is a test'
)
```

If you want to do things with `this is a test`, you can explode it out using something like `$testarr = explode(' ', $arr[1]);`.

You can then do something like:

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($testarr as $key => $value) {
   $value = strtoupper($value);
   if(($key+1)%4 == 0) { // % is modulus; the result is the remainder the division of two numbers. If it's 0, the key+1 (compensate for 0 based keys) is divisible by 4.
      $matches[] = $value;
   }
}
$matches = implode('"',$matches);
```

Comment: Sorry yeah the explode starts with the quote... and adds it back after the modifications. Hello World "This is a test"

Comment: Also my code is incorrect, im trying to count each word within quotes, get the index of each word and basically omit words by leaving certain values out. In simplest terms, always remove the fourth word in quotes...

Comment: I keep getting unexpected = on line 4 with that. I've been messing with it endlessly since i didn't get very many answers. Either way i appreciate your help. The most simple way to put what im looking for is take only words in quotes, label each one a number then take a few of the numbers and put them back in quotes. "[3] + [6]" would be "This Test"